# Is there a good solution for hosting a sound design/music portfolio online?

Tags: portfolio, design, music

Do any of you know of a good template-based portfolio site which caters for sound and music? I'm thinking of sites like http://carbonmade.com/ for visual media.

Or perhaps the best solution is just a link to a Vimeo account? Or one consolidated video?

My current portfolio is on Tumblr using a pretty nifty theme but I just feel like there's something better out there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Squarespace for hosting, Vimeo for video, and Soundcloud for audio.  That's the holy trinity as far as I can figure it.

Comment: bluehost.com is pretty cheap too, and offer a really easy wordpress installation

Comment: Don't use squarespace myself, but the vimeo/soundcloud combo wins the race for me too

Comment: Full disclosure, I don't use Squarespace myself, either.  (I edit the HTML directly, starting from a template.)  However, my wife uses Squarespace for her website, and it is a very easy-to-edit system.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend Behance.net. Free, unlimited everything, and it's a massive and very well-respected platform for creative professionals to network etc. Even has job listings. Best place to put your portfolio online in my opinion. I've gotten lots of work just from being part of Behance.

They also offer the new ProSite service if you want a fully customizable site with your own branding etc, which ties directly in to your Behance portfolio. Gotta be on Behance these days.

Comment: @theodorejordan thanks for the behance tip. I thought it was only Graphic artists on there, now that I've had a look, there is a strong sound design / composer collection on there.

Comment: I came to recommend Behance too :)

Comment: I tried clicking through that to listen to the audio. Just images though afaik. More than 3 clicks and I'm out!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Bandcamp](http://bandcamp.com). They even offer a way to sell your stuff if you want.

Or [Newgrounds Audio](http://www.newgrounds.com/audio/), which has a layout that not everyone might like, but they seem more geared towards music/sound for games, whereas Bandcamp is mostly about music from the artist's perspective.

Or dive into Wordpress and integrate [Soundcloud](http://soundcloud.com) and/or [Audioboo](http://audioboo.fm) with it. Lots of options and flexibility there, but also a steeper learning curve. You can host a Wordpress blog on [wordpress.com](http://wordpress.com) for free, or get your own hosting solution and [install](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress) it there for even greater freedom (and more effort).

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely vote for Vimeo/Soundcloud. Buy the soundcloud basic membership, which gets you more than enough space for an average portfolio of a few years, plus you can organize your material into "Sets" (e.g., film sound design, game sound effects, music production, etc.). I would recommend using one of the many free website designers out there to organize your sounds into a site with descriptions for each example, then embed your vimeo videos and soundcloud sounds in that site. Keeps things neater.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

GoDaddy hosting and Wordpress with a premium theme is my choice, then nicely embedding Vimeo and Soundcloud content in. Wordpress even has plugins and shortcodes specifically for Soundcloud etc though I personally use the nice 'Artwork Player' embed code from Soundcloud itself.

Comment: @Skarik boycott GoDaddy! they support SOPA don't they?

Answer (score 0):

If you're going with an hosting plan, better go with http://nearlyfreespeech.net/